# Doesn't Lua inheritance include metamethods?

Tags: oop, inheritance, lua, meta-method

I'm trying to implement simple inheritance in Lua as it is presented in [PIL 16.2](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.2.html). However, I've come across a surprising behavior: metamethods don't seem to be inherited. In the following example, I create a Point class with `x` and `y` members, and give it an `__add` metamethod. When adding instances of Point, everything works fine, but if I create a subclass and add instances of that, I get an error.

```
Point = {}

function Point:new(x, y)
    local point = {}
    setmetatable(point, self)
    self.__index = self
    point.x = x or 0
    point.y = y or 0
    return point
end

Point.__add = function(a, b)
    return Point:new(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y)
end

p = Point:new(2,2)
r1 = p + p
print(p.x, p.y) -- prints "4 4" as expected


ChildPoint = Point:new()
c = ChildPoint:new()

r2 = c + c -- Error: attempt to perform arithmetic on a table value (local 't1')
print(r.x, r.y)
```

I was expecting that Lua would look for `__add` in `ChildPoint`, and that would trigger `ChildPoint`'s `__index`, finding `__add` in `Point`. But that does not seem to happen.

Why does this not work, what actually happens, and (if this is correct behavior and not just a mistake of mine) how do I implement inheritable metamethods in Lua?

Comment: Unfortunately, metamethods are not inherited (I dont know why).  Lua manual says: "Note that queries for metamethods are always raw; the access to a metamethod does not invoke other metamethods."  You can copy all `__*` members from old metatable to new one when creating subclass (in this case you should create subclass with another function than create instance).  But this solution is not nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Egor explained, the metamethods need to be copied explicitly in this case; see this earlier [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155842/inheritance-for-metamethods-in-lua) for the discussion of the same problem and possible solutions (the selected one copies the metamethods).